# Dart's streams equivalent for javascript

Tags: javascript, dart

I'm searching a way to have something equal to Dart's streams API in Javascript. Do you know how I can get something similar ?

Comment: Maybe you wanna take a look at RxJS and BaconJS

Comment: Streams have a bunch of properties and it depends which one you wish to emulate, the first thing to consider would be dart2js, you can just use streams in dart and compile your program to js. Places where Iv wanted stream like objects in the past its where I want a chain of event listeners to listen to some point where events are being emitted from [like this](https://github.com/mrdoob/eventdispatcher.js/). its basically an array of functions and when the object emits an event it just calls each of those functions in turn passing in the event object. hope this was useful

Comment: Are you interested in the API or the underlying mechanism ?

Comment: I was interested by the mechanism. Now I see how it's working, I feel better :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have its own version of Dart's Streams, but there are many libraries that add the same sort of functionality. [RxJS](http://reactive-extensions.github.io/RxJS/) is a popular one created by Microsoft, for example.